# Entity Framework: How do I create a method to return data objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following `Method` which returns a record based on the `Primary Key` passed as argument:

```
class Program
{
    public static string GetRecord(Int64 pk)
    {
        using (var entityDataModel = new EntityDataModel())
        {
           var record = entityDataModel.Catalog.Find(pk);
           return record.VehicleMake;
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetRecord(7341367950));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Instead of the above, I need the Method to return an object that exposes records depending on what Primary key I pass as argument by the caller: What data type can I use here?

*Like this: (Example)*

```
   class Program
    {
        public static SomeDataType GetRecord(Int64 pk)
        {
            using (var entityDataModel = new EntityDataModel())
            {
                //Return record based on PK passed
               return entityDataModel.Catalog.Find(pk);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Call the method here and return the data object
            var record = GetRecord(7341367950);

            Console.WriteLine(record.VehicleMake);

            //Or like this:

            Console.WriteLine(GetRecord(7341367950).VehicleMake);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Update: Here is the Model:

```
public partial class EntityDataModel : DbContext
{
    public EntityDataModel()
        : base("name=EntityDataModel")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Catalog> Catalog { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Model> Model { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Catalog>()
            .Property(e => e.VehicleIdentificationNumber)
            .IsFixedLength();
    }
}
```

Comment: Whatever the data type of the model is. Since you define the model, only you know the type.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

I simply use the the Entity, in this case the Entity Model Catalog which represents a table in the database:

```
    public static Catalog GetRecord(Int64 pk)
    {
        using (EntityDataModel entityDataModel = new EntityDataModel())
        {
            return entityDataModel.Catalog.Find(pk);
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Catalog record = GetRecord(7341367950);
        Console.WriteLine(record.VehicleMake);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```